# PullRefreshIndicator circle always displaying on jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, pull-to-refresh

A blank grey circle of `PullToRefreshContainer` is always displaying even first time or after refreshing.

Here is my code

```
val pullRefreshState = rememberPullToRefreshState()

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .nestedScroll(connection = pullRefreshState.nestedScrollConnection)
) {
    // Another contents

    PullToRefreshContainer(
        modifier = Modifier.align(alignment = Alignment.TopCenter),
        state = pullRefreshState,
    )
}
```

Current compose version: `1.6.4`

[image]

Any help!